# Range error in copy range macro

Tags: vba, excel

I get an error on the first line trying to copy a value in the following VBA, I think the second part of the range is wrong, but can't detect the problem.

```
    Dim site As String
Dim People As Range
Dim AmountOfSites As Long
Dim AmountOfPeople As Long
Dim DestStartRow As Long
Dim DestEndRow As Long
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim sh3 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SiteName")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
Set sh3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
AmountOfSites = sh1.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
AmountOfPeople = sh2.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
DestStartRow = 2
DestEndRow = DestStartRow + AmountOfPeople

For i = 1 To AmountOfSites
    sh3.Range(Cells(DestStartRow, "A"), Cells((DestEndRow), "L")).Value = _
        sh2.Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(AmountOfPeople + 2, "L")).Value
    sh3.Range(Cells(DestStarRow, "M"), Cells(DestEndRow, "M")).Value = sh1.Cells(i, "A")
    DestStartRow = DestEndRow + 1
    DestEndRow = DestStarRow + AmountOfPeople
Next
```

Comment: All `Ranges` and `Cells` need to be qualified.  So `sh3.Range(sh3.Cells(...`

Comment: Yeps. Thanks! That was it, if you add an answer I can upvote it.

Comment: Glad I could help.  As much as I enjoy seeing my points go up, I am good with the comment.  Enjoy.

Comment: If you put in the answer, this thread will no longer be labeled as unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [@Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner):

> All `Ranges` and `Cells` need to be qualified. So `sh3.Range(sh3.Cells(...`

and according to OP:

> Yeps. Thanks! That was it

Comment: mannnnn this 1004 range error must pop up a dozen times a day. Do you know of any canonical answer we can use for the dupe-hammer?  If not, I'll just grab any similar Q with an accepted answer for duping.

Comment: I ignore dupes most days, too, mostly because it feels futile....  The thing is with most of these 1004 errors, it is *literally* the same problem and the same answer about 90% of the time -- so often in this case that I can identify it as dupe even without seeing the error code/etc.  There are other things that raise a 1004 to be sure, and a few other symptoms for the Method Range failed, but almost all the time it's this same problem of unqualified ranges.  /rant.

Comment: yeah, that's all that's kept me from writing it so far :)  There are basically 3 things that cause the 1004 Method Range failure: unqualified ranges which can't resolve to a valid range, typos which can't resolve to a valid range, and worksheet protection.  Any others?

Comment: I don't even know what they're suggesting, something about killing all running applications and then uninstalling "Microsoft Works", deleting some XLA file, and reparing the registry... waitaminute. Are you trolling me ?  :)

Comment: ahhh in that case then it's probably time to quiet down. getting late here, anyways.  shoot me a Hangout invite on Google (dzemens) and can probably cnonnect sometime tomorrow?

Comment: Fair enough, I rarely use the chat here but you can probably catch me tomorrow daytime eastern time. :)